# Count customers monthly is not working suing Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

My SQL Query is working fine.
count customers per month in SQL

```
SELECT YEAR(created_at) AS Year, MONTH(created_at) AS Month, COUNT(customer_id) as Customers FROM customers GROUP BY Year, Month
```

Query Builder equivalent to this.

```
$customers_permonth = DB::table('customers')->select('YEAR(created_at) as Year','MONTH(created_at) as Month')->groupBy('Year','Month')->count();
```

Error is :
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Year' in 'group statement' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `customers` group by `Year`, `Month`)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will fetch you all monthly customers

```
$customers_permonth = DB::table('customers')::selectRaw('COUNT(*) as count, YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month')
->groupBy('year', 'month')
->get();
```

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'year_month from `customers` group by `year_month`' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as customer_per_month, date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m') as year_month from `customers` group by `year_month`) ◀"

Comment: select the answer if helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use created_at in group by. Try following:

```
$customers_permonth = DB::table('customers')->select(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) as Year, MONTH(created_at) as Month, count(*) as count')->groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at)')->->get();
```

Comment: not working. Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'YEAR(created_at)' in 'group statement' (SQL: select count(`customer_id`) as aggregate from `customers` group by `YEAR(created_at)`, `MONTH(created_at) `)

Comment: @kapildevsharma:

try this: $customers_permonth = DB::table('customers')->select(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) as Year, MONTH(created_at) as Month, count(*) as count')->groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at)')->->get();